# excel sum if string

Tags: excel

I have a table similar to this:

```
102938 bob
038128 Marc
398401 Tom
298421 Jim
102938 Alex
102938 Junior
209381 Rex
398401 Oby
```

I want to make something like `=sumif(A:A, 102938,B:B)` which should return "bobAlexJunior" as the result.  But this is not working because `sum` works with numbers not strings. If I go with lookup, it works with strings but finds only first line, not all lines.

Do you have an idea on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There are two simple solutions:

1) Write a simple VLOOKUP formula in a third column and drag it. Then you can just select all then you can use a 4th column and concatenate all elements by using a reference to the 3rd column for the current element and concatenate with the previous element of the 4th column.

2) Using VBA, use Range.Find() on the first column and add the cell on its right to a temporary variable and return this.

Using a single formula would be way harder if it's possible. I have given it a quick try using array formulas and couldn't succeed (though I don't say it's impossible).

Answer (score 0):

This is not necessarily particularly elegant, but it might be a good starting point. If I'm understanding your requirement correctly, it boils down to the following goals:

1. Determine whether or not a particular row should be included in the concatenated string (e.g. if the left column = 102938)
2. Concatenate the text in the 2nd column together (but only for those rows that match the condition)

It seems Excel's CONCATENATE function doesn't accept a range (only an individual cell reference for each parameter). For a large number of rows it would obviously be tiresome to have to enter each cell manually, so I'd consider adding another column which acts incrementally.

For example, with the numbers in column A and the names in column B create a third column which will be the cumulative concatenated string.

Cell C1:

```
=IF(A1=102938,B1,"")
```

Cell C2:

```
=IF(A2=102938,CONCATENATE(C1, B2),C1)
```

Cell C3, C4 etc repeat C2's formula downwards.

So the table would look like this:

```
102938      bob     bob
38128       Marc    bob
398401      Tom     bob
298421      Jim     bob
102938      Alex    bobAlex
102938      Junior  bobAlexJunior
209381      Rex     bobAlexJunior
398401      Oby     bobAlexJunior
```

Then it's just a matter of picking the final row as your resut.

Comment: Hi, thank you very muh for your answer and effort. But I think this is not enough. This was just an example. I have table with 5000 rows where colA is not unique and I have another sheet where I have codes from colA but unique. I have to do for this other sheet with unique colA codes formula which will sum for me strings for every code. In google spreadhseet I can do it easily with =concatenate(filter(org!A$2:J$5585,org!B$2:B$5585=a2)) but here I don't have this kind of function :(.

Comment: Hi, no problem - I've written another answer based on this which might be more useful. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13446353/1145963

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach, taking into consideration your comment on my other answer (where you described that there are two sheets, one containing a list of names with codes, and one containing a list of unique codes, each with a concatenated list of the names).

You could create a custom function that accepts a range and a code and returns the concatenated string of names.

Paste the following VBA into a module (see [this link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/creating-custom-functions-HA001111701.aspx) if you're new to creating custom functions):

```
Function NamesWithCode(PeopleCodes As Range, CodeToMatch As String)
    Dim Result As String
    For Each Row In PeopleCodes.Rows
        If Row = CodeToMatch Then
            Result = Result & Row.Offset(0, 1)
        End If
    Next
    NamesWithCode = Result
End Function
```

Let's say your first worksheet is called "Names" and has two columns like you specified:

```
102938  bob
38128   Marc
398401  Tom
298421  Jim
102938  Alex
102938  Junior
209381  Rex
398401  Oby
```

In a second worksheet (say, "Codes"), you could use the new NamesWithCode function to lookup the name lists for each code, by passing in the full table from the first worksheet plus the code to look up for each row:

```
=NamesWithCode(Names!$A$1:$A$8, A2)
```

so the output would be:

```
Code    Names With Code
102938  bobAlexJunior
38128   Marc
398401  TomOby
298421  Jim
```